# Under what circumstances it is beneficial to asynchronously read a single file?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-3.7, python-aiofiles

I am new to python AIO, trying to learn. I am looking at [the aiofiles example](https://pypi.org/project/aiofiles/):

```
async with aiofiles.open('filename') as f:
    async for line in f:
```

and wondering under what circumstances it makes sense to asynchronously read a single file?
I understand IO operations will let the CPU do something else, but how this can be turned into a performance benefit?

Comment: https://realpython.com/async-io-python/#the-10000-foot-view-of-async-io This is from Real Python. It also has a really simple example...

Comment: This is my favorite article in the matter so far. Thank you @RomeoSierra!